# Anki - Next card review in <-36.2 years?

Tags: ankidroid

Was playing around with AnkiDroid, learning US of A state names as a test run. I just started today and AnkiDroid gives me the following options for cards I've seen already:

Again >1 minute, Hard 20 years, Good 50 years, Easy <-32.6 years

THat suppose to be normal?

Comment: That's not normal indeed... What version of AnkiDroid are you using?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Version 2.4.2; Found the problem. Phone's incorrect date and time threw AnkiDroid off correct statistics.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:** Date & time were incorrect on the phone when I was studying decks in AnkiDroid. After syncing to the correct time - AnkiDroid thought I've been studying a set of decks for years, not minutes.

Therefore, make sure your time is correctly set and preferably doesn't change to an incorrect value, otherwise don't use AnkiDroid when your date and time are wrong. **Set correct date and time first.**